# behavior of machine epsilon in simple arithmetic

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point

*using python x2

my homework asks me to set: eps = 2.**-52
the output of eps then becomes: 2.2204e-16

(1. + eps - 1. = 2.2204e-16)    # expected

(1. + eps/2. - 1. = 0.0)        # what?

My homework simply asks me what happened in the second equation. I've experimented with different sigfigs for the floats and reviewed resources but still don't understand.  Any help much appreciated!

Comment: eps/2. - 1. cannot be zero. It could be -1, though. Isn't there a typo somewhere?

Comment: Why is `eps - 1. = 2.2204e-16` expected? When `eps = 2.**-52` (almost zero) I expected `eps - 1.` to be about -1 (which is also what my Python2.7 interpreter gives me).

Comment: Do you mean `(1 + eps) - 1` and `(1 + eps/2) - 1`? `eps-1` is `-0.9999999999999998`, not `2.220446049250313e-16`.

Answer (score 0):

`(1 + eps/2.0) - 1 = 0.0` because `eps/2.0` is too small to be properly represented alongside 1 (it as called *absorption* or *cancellation*)

On a typical machine running Python, there are 53 bits of precision available for a Python float. If you try to go further, Python will eliminate the smallest part so the number can be properly represented.

In that case, 1 "wins" (1 "absorbs" `eps/2`), then substract to 1 and you get 0.

Comment: Ah, okay thank you very much!